# Simple PHP class for HTTP auth

Tags: php

I have a couple small web apps written in PHP that I only use myself. On my server, there is a `/secure` directory where I have access control with a `.htaccess` file. The apps themselves to not have any access control at all.

Now I would like to move them to a different server which runs with Lighttpd, where one cannot use `.htaccess` files and you need to be the admin to set HTTP auth for directories. So I thought to bake in HTTP auth into my apps. I was going to build a small class that reads an INI style file and query via HTTP basic auth for that.

Is that a good solution? Are there classes for that out there?

Comment: Have you checked the obvious code repositories like http://phpclasses.org/ or https://packagist.org/ ?

Comment: No, did not know about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One time I've written a supersimple FrontPlugin for Zend Framework for this, it would be easy to modify it :)

```
class MM_FrontPlugin_DevelopmentAccess extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler {

    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

        if(! isset($_SESSION['_devAccessPlugin'])) { // auth here instead of .htaccess

            if (! isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
                $this->sendAuthHeaders();
            else {

                if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'dev' AND $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'ilikecheesecake')
                    $_SESSION['_devAccessPlugin'] = true;
                else
                    $this->sendAuthHeaders();

            }

        }

    }

    private function sendAuthHeaders() {

        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Development zone, gtfo"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        exit;

    }

}
```